# Detect unused variables beyond a function scope

Tags: c++, c, optimization, unused-variables

Compilers detect unused variable within the scope of a function. However, I found there are many variables, defined inside a structure, which are never read (but may have been written many times). Is there any tool/analyzer or even compiler flags to detect such unused variables?

Example:
For example, in the following structure:

```
typedef struct jj_t {
    int count;
    int *list;
} jj;
```

Analyzer may find that `count` is never read anywhere in the code.

My analyze of my code, shows this frequently happens! This was my fault, but it maybe the common case for the applications developed by different users over the years. Removing these variable may significantly reduces memory usage. I just need a tool for detecting such variables and I will manually remove them.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Here is a list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tools_for_static_code_analysis#C.2FC.2B.2B) of static analysis tools for C and C++. Some of them might be able to detect your case.

Comment: Oh, I've got loads of those.  Can't be bothered to fix them.  Compared with my other massive development cockups that DID need fixing, this is too trivial an issue for me to deal with unless embedded code with limited RAM, (in which case, I'm eliminating every unused bit anyway).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can give one solution.

But:

1. The effort is probably much bigger than checking by hand. Almost every good IDE for programmers allows you to see all references to a given variable.
2. This probably won't work in every case, you'll need to specialize for some types.
3. This will be collected by single program run.

The idea is to wrap your data types. With such encapsulation you can count every read operation.
See:

```
template <class T, class Parent, int NO=1>
class TReadDetector {
public:
   struct Data {
      bool touched;
      Data () : touched(false) {}  
      ~Data ()  {
        if (!touched) 
          std::cerr << typeid(*this).name() << ": not read!!!\n" << std::endl;
      }  
   };
   static Data  data;
   TReadDetector () {}
   TReadDetector (const T& t) : t(t) {}
   operator T () const {    data.touched = true; return t; }
   TReadDetector& operator = (const T& t) { this->t = t; }
private:
   T t;
};

template <class T, class Parent, int NO>
typename TReadDetector<T,Parent,NO>::Data  
                       TReadDetector<T,Parent,NO>::data;
```

And usage:

Instead of:

```
struct A {
  int a;
  int b;
};
```

DO this:

```
struct A {
  TReadDetector<int,A, 1> a;
  TReadDetector<int,A, 2> b;
};


int main() {
  A a;
  a.a = 7;
  a.b = 8;
  std::cout << a.a << std::endl;
  std::cout << TReadDetector<int,A, 1>::data.touched << std::endl;
  std::cout << TReadDetector<int,A, 2>::data.touched << std::endl;
  std::cout << "main() ended" << std::endl;
};
```

It will results in:

```
7
1
0
main() ended
N13TReadDetectorIi1ALi2EE4DataE: not read!!!
```

Notice last line printed after `main()`. You can collect this data to some external file.

Comment: Well wrapper! I have a link list data struct and I use malloc() for allocation of one node and free() to release it. I think this is the reason why this wrappers do not detect the unused variable (Notice: I found the unused variable manually). I looks deconstructor is never called when using malloc/free! Am I right?

Comment: The d-tor of static element shall be called - as you can see in my example: it would work even if I changed `A a;` to `A * a  = new A;`. The reason this printout was not seen could be different - maybe after  `main()` all printouts were discarded. Anyway - this was not real solution - just an idea to show that tracking all readings of variable is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Any analysis would have to be accross translation units.

In practice, unlike you, I've never found this to be a problem.  About
the only solution I can think of off hand is to delete the members one by
one, and see if the entire application still compiles.

Comment: using __attribute__((deprecated)) would be a bit less radical than deleting ;-)

Comment: OK if the variable is no-read no-write. But what about no-read many-writes ?!

Answer (score -1):

Removing the field from the structure can be dangerous in few cases if we have used the structure like,

```
typedef struct jj_t {     int count;     int *list; } jj; 

jj *ptr = malloc (...);

//....

*ptr = 5; // NAIVE (but I have seen usage like this).
          // Actually you are not modifying count, count was already deleted.
```

So, very hard to do the analysis you were asking for.

Comment: -1. The presented code is not compilable because you cannot assign to a structure anything but another structure of this same type and yet you're trying to assign it an integer (5). Further, this doesn't answer the question. This would be fine for a comment.